# Linking dropdown to database table and dropdown to textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to link my dropdown that is already linked to one of tables  to my textboxes. what I want to achieve is to display the correspondent values of the table on the textboxes when choosing according value in the dropdown. I am using Visual Studio (ASP.NET) and Oracle database. Could someone tell me how to achieve that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can add attribute to dropdown list something like.

```
for(int i=0;i<dropdownlist.items;i++)
{
  dropdownlist.attributes.add(dropdownlist.items[i].value,//here get the value that you want to show in textbox from datasource or datatable)
}
```

on selected index changed.

```
dropdownlist.attributes[selectedvalue].ToString()
```

idea is to assign unique attribute to dropdown list with key as each items value.

Answer (score 0):

you could use linq to sql.....

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DB_ClassDataContext Inv = new DB_ClassDataContext(conn))
        {
            var inventory = (from inv in Inv.Inventories
                            where inv.ItemNumber == DropDownList2.Text
                            select new
                            {
                                itemName = inv.ItemName,
                                itemDesc = inv.ItemDesc,
                                itemPrice = inv.ItemPrice
                            }).First();


            var itemname = inventory.itemName;
            var itemdesc = inventory.itemDesc;
            var itemprice = inventory.itemPrice;

            txtItemName.Text = itemname;
            txtItemDesc.Text = itemdesc;
            txtItemPrice.Text = itemprice.ToString();

        }

    }
```